# How does Postgis store a low-level type in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis

For [`PostGIS`](https://postgis.net/), what mechanism do they use within Postgres to store the low-level (physical, logical) data type? Is there a mechanism that Postgres exposes whereby a third-party extension may create new native Data Types? I know they have [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createtype.html) at the SQL level, but I've been having difficulty locating the lower-level version of this if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is well documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html) how you can extend the PostgreSQL type system in C.